# Is there a way to flash a boot.img from recovery without a computer?

Tags: recovery-mode

Is there a way to flash a boot.img on your SD card without having to connect to a PC?

Is there an equivalent of the fastboot command?

I'm on a HTC Amaze 4G currently.

Comment: Do you have S-OFF? Which device are you using?

Comment: fastboot flash boot boot.img

Use this in fastboot mode.

Comment: HTC Amaze 4G, no S-Off, it flipped to S-On on recently trying to install a new ROM. No luck yet. I've also tried fastboot in the terminal of TWRP recovery, but it says fastboot -> no such command.

Comment: From what I understand now, it seems I won't be able to flash anything without S-Off, I'll try that and see if maybe fastboot then becomes available.

Comment: fastboot can't be used from the recovery

Answer (score 1):

Once you have S-OFF you should be able to flash a custom recovery.  Just flash one that supports IMG files, such as ClockworkMod ([ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager)).

Comment: I was able to install 4ext, with S-On still active.

Comment: Yes that is possible, but flashing roms through recovery will not flash the boot.img due to S-ON status. boot.img has to be flashed through fastboot via pc. See my previous comments for the command to be used from your computer terminal/command-prompt.